# How can I run play application to be visible across the network?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I cloned my application on Amazon EC2. When I type `sbt run`, it runs on localhost (by the way, I can't look at it via lynx, is it ok?)

Tried to `sbt run -Dhttp.port=port -Dhttp.address=my.amazon.public.ip`, but from regular browser I get `This webpage is not available` on `my.amazon.public.ip:port`.

Also I need exactly Amazon, not Heroku etc.

So, how can I run application to be visible across the network, not only localhost?

Comment: Are you sure? I think it binds to 0.0.0.0 (play 2.3 atleast), not localhost

Comment: I meant, I tested it on localhost while developing (localhost:9000 in browser). I have "[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000" after `sbt run`

Comment: Are you literally using the string `my.amazon.public.ip` ?

Comment: No, I have smth like 12.34.56.789. So, full command to start app is `sbt -Dhttp.port=8080 -Dhttp.address=12.34.56.789 run`.

Answer (score 0):

Just did not open the port in Security Group. After that, everything worked.